# Buffer Error-Error converting result java.lang.nul... and JSON Parser-Error parsing data org.json.JSONException

Tags: java, android, json, bufferedreader

I'm building an application in android to record attendance of staff, the application reads the code of personnel from a QR code and updates on a table in the database.

I have two problems:

**Buffer Error-Error converting result java.lang.null.PointerException
JSON Parser-Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input ar character 0 of**

Heres is the MainActivity

```
package com.example.asistenciai;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;




public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_update_attendance = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/update_attendance.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_COD = "cod";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    //1. LOCALIZAR CONTROLES
    final Button btnRegistrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnRegistrar);

    btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        });

   }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
       if (requestCode == 0) {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            if(contents.equals("64572215")){
                new ActualizarAsistencia().execute();

                /*Intent i = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ResultadoOkActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);*/  
             }else{ 
                Intent i = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ResultadoFalloActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
             }
          } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
             // Handle cancel
          }
       }
    }

    class ActualizarAsistencia extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MenuActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving attendance ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            //this is an example
            String cod = "64572215";


            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_COD, cod));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_attendance,
                    "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ResultadoFalloActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }


    }


}
```

and here's the JSONParser class

```
package com.example.asistenciai;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Errore converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Errore parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

the logcat

```
05-31 18:08:28.325: E/Buffer Error(25370): Errore converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 18:08:28.325: E/JSON Parser(25370): Errore parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at com.example.asistenciai.MenuActivity$ActualizarAsistencia.doInBackground(MenuActivity.java:109)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at com.example.asistenciai.MenuActivity$ActualizarAsistencia.doInBackground(MenuActivity.java:1)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-31 18:08:28.360: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    ... 5 more
```

grateful if you could help me!

Comment: please post coplete LogCat.

Comment: ok i put the logcat now

Comment: the line 109 is this
    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

Comment: and What is the JSON Object that you are trying to parse look like?

Comment: getint receives a string and returns an Int ... or no? :/

Comment: ^ You're right. I deleted that comment.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you are getting the following in `LogCat`:

`Buffer Error-Error converting result java.lang.null.PointerException JSON Parser-Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:`

So, the possibility of error is that your `is` variable is null when calling following statement:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

So it is returning a null pointer exception. As it is set in the try-catch block, it is goint to `catch` and showing `Buffer Error: ...` and then as `json` variable would be null(coz `is` was null), so now when you are trying to parse the object, `jObj`variable  would also throw an exception. So now you also get `JSON parse error`.

You have to make sure that `is` is not null. 
Try and put the whole `BufferReader` stuff and the parsing stuff in the same try-catch block in which you are setting the `is` variable's value. It can be that your `BufferReader` is taking the null, by which you initialized the variable `is` on the top. So try and have all of it inside the same try() block. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `json` variable is null. So the method `makeHttpRequests` of your `JSONParser` returns `null`. Probably the problem is on following lines:

```
if(method == "POST") {
    ...
} else if (method == "GET") {
    ...
}
```

You can't compare strings with `==`, but you should use `equals()`. Like this:

```
if(method.equals("POST")){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I modified it and still throwing the same error, other possibilities? :/

Comment: Well after correcting the 2 `if` statements you correct this exception: `Errore converting result java.lang.NullPointerException`. Now if the code still doesn't work you should get other exceptions, don't you?
By the way you should post the JSON object you want to parse too.